# How to automatically make all entries to become Hyperlinks to files in folder in Microsoft Access Database

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-access-2010

I have Microsoft Access database, where I want to keep hyperlinks for the pdf files. I got the list of filenames and put in corresponding fields in my database. I made that Field of Hyperlink Data Type. I am wondering is there any way I can make all that fields to become hyperlink not manually (because I have 224 entries, and I am going to add the pdf files constantly). The database is located in the same folder as the pdf files so I use just filename. I use Windows 7 Enterprise and Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When the field's data type is changed to `Hyperlink` all of the existing records in the table will become hyperlinks.

**Note:** If the field wasn't a complete hyperlink path initially, the hyperlinks may or may not work after you change the field type. So, you may have to modify them all anyway.

Comment: It worked out. First I make my paths complete (C:\Users\...\P\PRL92_077402_04.pdf) then changed the Data Type to Text, Saved it, then changed back to Hyperlink. Thanks a lot.